# File Stream problems

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In 2010 Visual C++ Express, I'm using
...

```
ifstream inFile("inputfile.dat");
double number;
while(inFile >> number)
{
cout << number << endl;
}
```

...to read 8 numbers stored in a file into the program, and show them on the monitor. It shows them all correctly and as needed, but I need to store each individual number as already specified doubles. From top to bottom,

1. Customer 1's Identification #
2. Balance
3. Payments outstanding
4. Purchases that have been made

then the other 4 numbers are the same thing just for a different customer. I've tried a ton of different ways to do it, but each come with:

```
"Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'variableName' is 
 being used without being initialized."
```

and it happens with almost all of the variables. I've searched for anything to help me with this but couldn't seem to find something that would help me to the extent of what I needed.

Comment: Show the code that's failing.

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what is happening. Try to initialize all your variables before to use them: double number = 0.0; Of course you have another problem with your code, but now you can take a look into cout outputs and try to figure out by yourself the problem.

Comment: @HugoCorrá More likely, he's using a warning level or something like that that's too strict (maybe /W4). It's ok to pass uninitialized variables to basic_istream::operator>>, because you're passing it by reference, not by value, and basic_istream::operator>> won't try to use its value (in other words it's an out parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you really want to store these in 8 distinct variables, and not in some aggregate data type:

```
std::ifstream inFile("inputfile.dat");
double number;

    if(inFile >> cust1id >> cust1bal >> cust1pay >> cust1purch >> 
                 cust2id >> cust2bal >> cust2pay >> cust2purch) {
      std::cout << 
        "Customer 1's Identification #: " << cust1id << "\n" <<
        "Balance: " < cust1bal << "\n" <<
        "Payments outstanding: " << cust1pay << "\n" <<
        "Purchases that have been made: " << cust1purch << 
        "Customer 2's Identification #: " << cust2id << "\n" <<
        "Balance: " < cust2bal << "\n" <<
        "Payments outstanding: " << cust2pay << "\n" <<
        "Purchases that have been made: " << cust2purch << "\n"; 
     }
```